# Computing the integral of $-1/f''$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, closed-form

I think this is a very silly question but I have some problems nonetheless.

If I know that $g'=-\frac{1}{f''}$, is then
$$
g=(f')^{-1}?
$$

Comment: No, then $g' = -\frac{f''}{(f')^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no formula *in general* to get a closed form of 
$$
\int\frac1{f''}
$$

We have
$$
\left(\frac1f\right)'=-\frac{f'}{f^2}
$$ and your expression for $g$ is not correct in general.